# Are all members of following structs and arrays initialized with zero?

Tags: c++

Furthermore, is there a difference between the initialization of the variables one and two, and the initialization of the varibles three and four? Background of the Question is, that i get an compiler error in Visual Studio 6.0 with the initialization of variable two and four. With Visual Studio 2008 it compiles well.

```
struct stTest
{
  int a;
  char b[10];
};

stTest one = {0};
stTest two = {};
stTest three[10] = {0};
stTest four[10] = {};
```

Comment: This all should be valid syntax. What is the nature of the compiler error and can you provide an example that wraps this snippet in a short `main()` that still causes the error?

Comment: Visual Studio 6.0 had serious problems in conforming to the standards.  Microsoft has done a lot of work, and VS 2008 is very close to the standard, although there's a few minor issues left.

Comment: Visual Studio 6 had no real standards to conform to. It was released before the first C++ standard came out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all of them a required to be initialized with 0 by the language standard (C++98).

Visual Studio 6 is known not to perform the proper handling of `{}` case: it doesn't even support `{}` syntax, if I remember correctly.

However, Visual Studio 6 is a pre-standard compiler. It was released before the C++98 standard came out.

Answer (score 1):

See [Michael Burr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352370/c-static-array-initialization-how-verbose-do-i-need-to-be/1352379#1352379) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352370/c-static-array-initialization-how-verbose-do-i-need-to-be).

The short answer is yes, but a little emphasis sometimes helps, *e.g.*,

```
stTest s = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

The initializations are the same. Visual Studio 2.0 is broken.

---

Edit:

Yes, they are initialized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

([Ripped from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64973255%28VS.80%29.aspx))

If I have a structure called tPoint ...

```
    struct tPoint {   
        int x;   
        int y;
    };
```

... and I use it as follows ...

```
tPoint spot {10,20};
```

... I can expect that members x and y will be initialized.

As for your first question, I'd expect that the array b is not initialized because you only give one value for initialization.

You can initialize the values to zero by default:

```
struct stTest
{
  int a = 0;
  char b[10] = {0};
};
```

You can initialize the array like this:

```
char i[10] = {0};
stTest one = {0, i};
```

As for why it compiles with VS 2008 and not VS 6.0, VS 2008 probably ignores the empty set and doesn't try to initialize anything.