# How can I check if a variable in a struct is not used in C?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Here is the code I have so far.

I am trying to be able to tell if a certain variable inside a struct is empty. I am going to be creating a struct with some variables being filled and some not and need to know which ones need me to do something and which ones don't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nums {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
} typedef numbers;

int main() {
    numbers bob;

    bob.a = 69;

    if (bob.b == NULL) {
        printf("no number stored in b");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I just get the error

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A variable in C cannot be 'empty'. In your example, the value never has been set so it is *undefined* - it van be anything.

Comment: At the cost of some overhead you could have add a bit-field member to the struct treating it as a collection of flags where bit i is set to 1 if and only if the ith struct member has been set. In addition to the memory overhead that is entailed you would need to properly initialize it and make sure that it is updated as needed.

Comment: Any ideas...regarding the error? The warning message itself is quite clear: you're comparing an integer (bob.b) with a pointer (NULL). In case you have a SQL background... Please note C-NULL has nothing to do with SQL-NULL

Comment: This is a very awkward way to use `typedef`.  It is not strictly incorrect, but highly unusual and most programmers will be wondering why you code even compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there is no way to tell if you have actually stored something in an `int` variable.

In your case, though, you could:

- Initialize your struct: `numbers bob = { 0 }; // <-- this makes a, b, c, d equal to zero`
- Then check if you have any number **different** than `0`:

  ```
  if(bob.b == 0){
          printf("no non-zero number stored in b");
  }
  ```

Comment: .. But of course 0 is a valid integer so it is "not empty" or is it? Perhaps INT_MAX would be a better choice

Comment: @EdHeal - you're right. This is just a suggestion for him to check if he actually stores something different than 0 in his struct. I did not mention 0 as "empty" or "no-filled"

Comment: Your solution seems to assign a special meaning to zero. Why not `if(bob.b == 23) { printf("no non-twentythree number stored in b");}` ? OP should understand  that you cannot say if a variable was set or not by just looking the variable content.

Comment: @mauro - it depends on the context that a zero can have a special meaning. I did mention that "Usually there is no way to tell if you have actually stored something in an int variable."

Comment: @mauro I can see your point, but your example is an exaggeration. Of course, if you have number 23 there then it must have been assigned explicitly. Number zero is the default value when you initialize `numbers bob = {};`

Comment: @artm but one could have executed `bob.b=0;` right before your if. Anyhow... I think we have understood each other's point.

Comment: @chqrlie - agree, the empty braces {} are C++ standard, C requires {0}. I'm editing this - thanks.

Comment: {} vs {0} - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352370/c-static-array-initialization-how-verbose-do-i-need-to-be/1352379#1352379

and,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003574/explicit-initialization-of-struct-class-members

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do has not sense in C.
The only solution is to analyze your code and to proof, with a logical analysis, that certain variable is used (or not).

I'll give two ideas that can help you, anyway.

**1. INITIALIZATION TO DUMMY VALUE**

One could choose a value in the range of the type of the variable that we know that it has not a meaning among the values that our program handle.
For example, for the `int` type one could choose `INT_MIN` as such a dummy value.
It's the most negative value that the `int` type can hold.
In 32-bit 2's complement `int`s this value is `-2147483648`, which is probably your case.
[`INT_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>`, so you have to `#include` it.]

```
#include <limits.h>
numbers bob = { INT_MIN, INT_MIN, INT_MIN, INT_MIN};  
if (bob.b == INT_MIN) puts("Unused object.");
```

This method works, provided that you never have `INT_MIN` as a valid value in the rest of your program.

**2. CHANGE YOUR APPROACH**

Instead of using `int`, one could use a `pointer to an int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct { int *a, *b, *c, *d; } pnumbers;  
int main(void) {
  pnumbers bob = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };  
  int val = 32;  
  bob.a = &val;
  bob.c = malloc(sizeof(int));
  bob->c = 20;
  if (bob.a != NULL) printf("%d\n", bob->a);  
  if (bob.b == NULL) puts("Unused member");  
  if (bob.c != NULL) printf("%d\n", bob->c);  
}
```

Comment: Regarding your 1st approach, there is no difference from INT_MIN and zero - these are all valid values, and so user has to make the assumption that either number is never used.