# Different assembly when initializing an array with a string literal

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, array-initialization

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8244453/1488067), initializing an array with a shorter string literal pads the array with zeros.

So, is there any reason why these two functions (`test1` and `test2`) would produce different results when compiled for ARM Cortex M4?

```
extern void write(char * buff);

void test1(void)
{
    char buff[8] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    write(buff);
}

void test2(void)
{
    char buff[8] = "test";
    write(buff);
}
```

I am getting [equivalent assemblies for x86-64](https://godbolt.org/z/WOeBbD), but on ARM gcc I get [different output](https://godbolt.org/z/PgPkl5):

```
test1:
        str     lr, [sp, #-4]!
        sub     sp, sp, #12
        mov     r3, sp
        ldr     r2, .L4
        ldm     r2, {r0, r1}
        stm     r3, {r0, r1}
        mov     r0, r3
        bl      write
        add     sp, sp, #12
        ldr     pc, [sp], #4
.L4:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
test2:
        mov     r3, #0
        str     lr, [sp, #-4]!
        ldr     r2, .L8
        sub     sp, sp, #12
        ldm     r2, {r0, r1}
        str     r0, [sp]
        mov     r0, sp
        strb    r1, [sp, #4]
        strb    r3, [sp, #5]
        strb    r3, [sp, #6]
        strb    r3, [sp, #7]
        bl      write
        add     sp, sp, #12
        ldr     pc, [sp], #4
.L8:
        .word   .LANCHOR0+8
```

Comment: As far as the C standard is concerned, these are equivalent. Though a compiler will be allowed to skip writing zeroes after the null terminator, if it can deduct that the memory after `\0` isn't used (which it can't here, due to external linkage). So it rather seems like this is some manner of bug. If I change `test2` to `char buff[8] = "test\0\0\0";` (4 trailing zeroes) I get identical machine code for both cases on ARM too.

Comment: BTW: buff gets filled up with `0` if you use `{'t', 'e', 's', 't', 0 }`, too. I'd expect that this produces the same assembler output as the string literal version.

Comment: @StephanLechner: [it does](https://godbolt.org/z/WOeBbD), except when compiling with arm gcc.

Comment: x86-64 is a 64-bit architecture (and zero-extends 32-bit immediates to 64-bit for free), so it's unsurprising for multiple reasons that both versions use a single qword store.  If you make the array 9 bytes long, and add a 5th non-zero byte (https://godbolt.org/z/Xk-vLP), you get significantly different code from gcc (with some silly test1 code), but clang still makes identical good code for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, the code is equivalent in the sense that the contents of memory constituting the objects named `buf` will be the same.

That said, the compiler clearly produces worse code for the second function. Consequently, since there is a way to produce more optimized code that has equivalent semantics, it would be reasonable to consider this an optimization failure in the compiler and file a bug for it.

If the compiler wanted to emit the same code, it would have to recognize that the string literal representation in memory can be zero-padded without changing the semantics of the program (though the string literal itself cannot be padded, since `sizeof "test"` cannot be equal to `sizeof "test\0\0\0"`).

However, since this would *only* be advantageous if the string literal is used to initialize an explicit-length array (usually a bad idea) that is longer than the literal and where normal string semantics are not sufficient (bytes past the null-terminator are relevant), the value of better optimization for this case seems limited.

Addendum: If you set godbolt to not remove assembler directives, you can see how the literals are created:

```
.section        .rodata
.align  2
.set    .LANCHOR0,. + 0
.byte   116
.byte   101
.byte   115
.byte   116
.byte   0
.byte   0
.byte   0
.byte   0
.ascii  "test\000"
.space  3
```

Interestingly, the compiler does not deduplicate, and it leaves the padding after the string literal to the assembler (`.space 3`), rather than explicitly zeroing it.